# Java XML, The number of formal and actual parameters differs, or an unwrapping conversion has failed

Tags: java-8, ejb, jersey-2.0, jaxb2

When requesting data from endpoint with `accept: application/xml` I keep getting the following error:

> javax.xml.bind.MarshalException
>    - with linked exception: [Exception [EclipseLink-27] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.6.1.v20150916-55dc7c3):
>   org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DescriptorException Exception
>   Description: Trying to invoke the method [getSurveyid] on the object
>   [com.on24.ejb.mapping.SurveyQuestion].  The number of actual and
>   formal parameters differs, or an unwrapping conversion has failed.
>   Internal Exception: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: object is not
>   an instance of declaring class Mapping:
>   org.eclipse.persistence.oxm.mappings.XMLDirectMapping[surveyid-->surveyid/text()]
>   Descriptor: XMLDescriptor(com.on24.ejb.mapping.Survey -->
>   [DatabaseTable(survey)])]

The response works fine when `accept: application/json` so I know it can't be a problem extracting the info from DB; I just haven't been able to solve this issue so any help will be greatly appreciated.

DTOs involved:

```
@XmlRootElement
@XmlType (propOrder={"surveyid",
"surveyquestions"})
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.PUBLIC_MEMBER)
public class Survey {
    private Long surveyid;
    private List<SurveyQuestion> surveyquestions;

    public Survey(){}

    public Long getSurveyid() {
        return surveyid;
    }

    public void setSurveyid(Long surveyid) {
        this.surveyid = surveyid;
    }

    @XmlElementWrapper(name="surveyquestionslist")
    @XmlElement(name="surveyquestion")
    public List<SurveyQuestion> getSurveyquestions() {
        return surveyquestions;
    }

    public void setSurveyquestions(List<SurveyQuestion> surveyquestions) {
        this.surveyquestions = surveyquestions;
    }
}
```

And

```
@XmlRootElement
@XmlType (propOrder={"surveyquestionid",
"surveyquestion",
"surveyanswers"})
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.PUBLIC_MEMBER)
public class SurveyQuestion {
    private Long surveyquestionid;
    private String surveyquestion;
    private List<String> surveyanswers;


    public SurveyQuestion(){}

    public Long getSurveyquestionid() {
        return surveyquestionid;
    }

    public void setSurveyquestionid(Long surveyquestionid) {
        this.surveyquestionid = surveyquestionid;
    }

    public String getSurveyquestion() {
        return surveyquestion;
    }

    public void setSurveyquestion(String surveyquestion) {
        this.surveyquestion = surveyquestion;
    }

    @XmlElementWrapper(name="surveyanswerslist")
    @XmlElement(name="surveyanswer")
    public List<String> getSurveyanswers() {
        return surveyanswers;
    }

    public void setSurveyanswers(List<String> surveyanswers) {
        this.surveyanswers = surveyanswers;
    }
}
```

I've tried several thinks from refactoring to use `XmlAccessType.PUBLIC_MEMBER, XmlAccessType.FIELD, XmlAccessType.PROPERTY` but no success there.

I'd really like to understand why this error is generated. If more info is need I'll add it as per asked for, thanks.